# How to get variables from a method running on an independent thread from other classes?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

Suppose I have 2 classes: `Form1.cs` and `Step.cs`

In class `Form` I call a method from class `Step` and assign it on a new thread avoiding conflict with the UI.

Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Step test_step = new Step();

    public void main_run_auto() {
        test_step.TakeAction();
    }

    public void function_1() {
        Thread thread_1 = new Thread(() => main_run_auto());
        thread_1.start();
    }
}
```

Step.cs

```
public class Testing_Steps_class
{
    public void TakeAction() {
        string status = "";

        // Step 1
        ...do something...
        status = "Updated Stt 1";

        // Step 2
        ...do something...
        status = "Updated Stt 2";

        // Step 3
        ...do something...
        status = "Updated Stt 3";

    }
}
```

My question is: How can I get the variable status updated instantly on a textbox or datagridview row in class `Form1`?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using BackgroundWorker ?https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: `TakeAction` has no return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly that variable you want to transfer is but one way of doing it is, since you have an instance of the `Class` `Step` creating a custom event which transfers your variable.
Example transfering an exception:

```
 public class Test1
 {
    public delegate void HandleErrorGenerated(Exception exc, string method);
    public event HandleErrorGenerated ExceptionGenerated;

    private void OnExceptionGenerated(Exception exc, string method)
    {
        if (ExceptionGenerated != null)
        {
            ExceptionGenerated(exc, method);
        }
        else
        {
            throw exc;
        }
    }

    private void MethodInMyThread()
    {
         try
         {
         //do stuff
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             OnExceptionGenerated(e, "MethodInMyThread");
         }
    }

 }



 public class Form1
 {
     Test1 theTest = new Test1();
     public Form1()
     {
         Test1.ExceptionGenerated += test1_ExceptionGenerated;
     }

     private void test1_ExceptionGenerated(Exception exc, string method)
     {
          //handle variable passed
     }
 }
```

Another way of going about it is passing a variable with `ref` from the `Form` to the `Step` class and inside the step class method update its value. [MSDN Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

Then use the invoke method as Hari Prasad said.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access controls created on `UI` thread from other thread. You have to use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` for to change the `UI`.

```
public void TakeAction() {        

    // Step 1
    ...do something...
    UpdateUI("Updated Stt 1");

    // Step 2
    ...do something...
    UpdateUI("Updated Stt 2");

    // Step 3
    ...do something...
    UpdateUI("Updated Stt 3");

}

void UpdateUI(string message)
{
    Textbox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
    {
       textbox1.Text= message;
    }));    
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have a question: if I want to access controls on UI from another class, I must use `Invoke` no matter the method is running on another thread, is this correct? If I use `Invoke` does it update the checkbox instantly on UI? And in case I don't want to show text on the textbox, but I want to take the latest status variable to create a log file, can I use `Invoke` or I have to use other things? Thank you.

Comment: The method `UpdateUI` in your code is not working because `textbox1` does not exist in class `Step`.

Comment: When you want to access `UI controls` from any other thread , yes you have to use `invoke` or `BeginInvoke`.  Does it update immediately, Yes it does. Logging and any other actions normally allowed to run on executing thread itself, no need to call `Invoke`

Comment: `textbox1` is just an example as you said textbox in question, you can use control name you used in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean I did use my control name but it didn't get the textbox. Do I need to create an object Form1 to call the textbox or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108876/discussion-between-louis-tran-and-hari-prasad).

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/SgzvX3lNxD Please take a look at the screenshot. Class Step doesn't contain txtStatus, how can you use it?

Comment: Your code only works in class `Form1`. But the method is in class `Step`. They are different classes. You can't not `invoke` textbox txtStatus like that.

Comment: Is step class in different assembly/library? If not just include name space that  Form1 belongs to in Step.cs file